# Java String Builder append computation

Tags: java, concatenation, stringbuilder

When I use StringBuilder's append, when does the actual copying happens - when I call append() or when I evaluate the builder as a string?

I'm asking because in my application I have alot of log.debug(strA+strB+...) lines and I want to avoid evaluating the concatenations in production code. I know java optimizes the + ops and turns them to string builder appends but I don't know if the concatenation really happens or not in the append function.

Comment: You should have a look at slf4j which has log methods that take a string format and objects for substitution.

Comment: The concatenation happens in the append function. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.append%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` contains an array of characters. `append()` adds characters to that array. Once you call `stringBuilderInstance.toString()` either explicitly or implicitly, then a new String instance is created based on the contents of stringbuilder.

Answer (score 3):

In `StringBuilder` when you append, it means you are concatenating strings. No, extra object is created internally. It is just append! When you convert `StringBuilder` to `String` using `.toString()`, copy of content happens from `StringBuilder` to `String` object.

Answer (score 1):

Both. When you append to a `StringBuilder` you are copying characters into its internal character array. When you convert the builder to a string you copy the contents into the internal array of the `String` instance.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` extends `AbstractStringBuilder` and there are several `append` methods inside:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(Object obj) {
    return append(String.valueOf(obj));
}

public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return appendNull();
    int len = str.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}


public AbstractStringBuilder append(StringBuffer sb) {
    if (sb == null)
        return appendNull();
    int len = sb.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    sb.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}

AbstractStringBuilder append(AbstractStringBuilder asb) {
    if (asb == null)
        return appendNull();
    int len = asb.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    asb.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}

@Override
public AbstractStringBuilder append(CharSequence s) {
    if (s == null)
        return appendNull();
    if (s instanceof String)
        return this.append((String)s);
    if (s instanceof AbstractStringBuilder)
        return this.append((AbstractStringBuilder)s);

    return this.append(s, 0, s.length());
}
```

it uses `char[] value;` declaration to declare storage for all characters.
When you append new string, it checks current length of `value` array, and if it is necessary, it calls `ensureCapacityInternal`:

```
private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minimumCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    if (minimumCapacity - value.length > 0)
        expandCapacity(minimumCapacity);
}
```

And it calls `expandCapacity` when it is necessary:

```
/**
 * This implements the expansion semantics of ensureCapacity with no
 * size check or synchronization.
 */
void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = value.length * 2 + 2;
    if (newCapacity - minimumCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
    if (newCapacity < 0) {
        if (minimumCapacity < 0) // overflow
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
}
```

**Conclusion:** copying is calling *when you append* new data and the capacity of character `values` array is not enough to store this new data.